# Taylor expansion of $\sin(x-y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

A question asks me to find the partial derivatives of $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x, y) = \sin(x-y)$ then asks me to give the taylor expansion of $f(\pi/2+h, k)$ in powers of $h$ and $k$ upto and including second order terms. My trouble is I don't understand what the question is asking. I keep evaluating the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(x, y) = (\pi/2+h, k)$ and that gives me an equation that doesn't simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula to use is the following 
\begin{align*}
f(\pi/2+h,k) & \approx f(\pi/2,0)+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\pi/2,0)+k\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\pi/2,0)+\frac{h}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(\pi/2,0)\\
& + \frac{k}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(\pi/2,0)+ hk \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(\pi/2,0).
\end{align*} This is simply the Taylor's formula at $(\pi/2,0)$ expanded to order $2$. Can you now finish the exercice ?

Comment: Thank you. Could I ask something, though, what's the purpose of $h$ and $k$ here, if they wanted the expansion of $f$ at $(\pi/2, 0)$? That's what confused me. In other words, what's the difference between $f(\pi/2, 0)$ and $f(\pi/2+h, k)$?

Comment: You assume that $h$ and $k$ are small. Hence $f(\pi/2+h,k)$ is the value of $f$ near $f(\pi/2,0)$. Of course these are not equal and the error of this approximation can be quantified thanks to the derivatives.